# Linking error with CGAL

Tags: c++, cgal

I have CGAL installed on my Mac OS X (10.8.4).  I have successfully incorporated aspects of CGAL into previous C++ programs to compute the convex hull of a 3D point cloud.  However, now I am trying to include other parts of CGAL for computing surface meshes, converting them to polyhedra, and so on.  When I do that, the program compiles just fine, but then I receive linking errors that I don't understand.

Here is my linking command following compilation:

> c++ -O2 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/opt/local/include -o /Users/bullard/ShapeMetrology/Particle/bin/diffgeom diffgeom.a  -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -L/opt/local/lib -lboost_math_c99 -lm  -lCGAL -lCGAL_Core -lCGAL_ImageIO -lgmp

And here are the (rather verbose) linking errors I am receiving:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "boost::detail::get_tss_data(void const*)", referenced from:
>         CGAL::Lazy, CGAL::Gmpq, CGAL::Lazy_exact_nt, CGAL::To_interval >::zero() in diffgeom.a(Particle.o)
>         boost::thread_specific_ptr, CGAL::Gmpq, CGAL::Lazy_exact_nt, CGAL::To_interval > >::reset(CGAL::Lazy, CGAL::Gmpq, CGAL::Lazy_exact_nt, CGAL::To_interval >*) in diffgeom.a(Particle.o)
>         CGAL::Lazy > >, CGAL::Point_3 >, CGAL::Gmpq, CGAL::Cartesian_converter, CGAL::Simple_cartesian >, CGAL::NT_converter > > >::zero() in diffgeom.a(Particle.o)
>         boost::thread_specific_ptr > >, CGAL::Point_3 >, CGAL::Gmpq, CGAL::Cartesian_converter, CGAL::Simple_cartesian >, CGAL::NT_converter > > > >::reset(CGAL::Lazy > >, CGAL::Point_3 >, CGAL::Gmpq, CGAL::Cartesian_converter, CGAL::Simple_cartesian >, CGAL::NT_converter > > >*) in diffgeom.a(Particle.o)
>         CGAL::Lazy > >, CGAL::Sphere_3 >, CGAL::Gmpq, CGAL::Cartesian_converter, CGAL::Simple_cartesian >, CGAL::NT_converter > > >::zero() in diffgeom.a(Particle.o)
>         boost::thread_specific_ptr > >, CGAL::Sphere_3 >, CGAL::Gmpq, CGAL::Cartesian_converter, CGAL::Simple_cartesian >, CGAL::NT_converter > > > >::reset(CGAL::Lazy > >, CGAL::Sphere_3 >, CGAL::Gmpq, CGAL::Cartesian_converter, CGAL::Simple_cartesian >, CGAL::NT_converter > > >*) in diffgeom.a(Particle.o)
>     "boost::detail::set_tss_data(void const*, boost::shared_ptr, void*, bool)", referenced from:
>         boost::thread_specific_ptr, CGAL::Gmpq, CGAL::Lazy_exact_nt, CGAL::To_interval > >::reset(CGAL::Lazy, CGAL::Gmpq, CGAL::Lazy_exact_nt, CGAL::To_interval >*) in diffgeom.a(Particle.o)
>         boost::thread_specific_ptr, CGAL::Gmpq, CGAL::Lazy_exact_nt, CGAL::To_interval > >::~thread_specific_ptr() in diffgeom.a(Particle.o)
>         boost::thread_specific_ptr > >, CGAL::Point_3 >, CGAL::Gmpq, CGAL::Cartesian_converter, CGAL::Simple_cartesian >, CGAL::NT_converter > > > >::reset(CGAL::Lazy > >, CGAL::Point_3 >, CGAL::Gmpq, CGAL::Cartesian_converter, CGAL::Simple_cartesian >, CGAL::NT_converter > > >*) in diffgeom.a(Particle.o)
>         boost::thread_specific_ptr > >, CGAL::Point_3 >, CGAL::Gmpq, CGAL::Cartesian_converter, CGAL::Simple_cartesian >, CGAL::NT_converter > > > >::~thread_specific_ptr() in diffgeom.a(Particle.o)
>         boost::thread_specific_ptr > >, CGAL::Sphere_3 >, CGAL::Gmpq, CGAL::Cartesian_converter, CGAL::Simple_cartesian >, CGAL::NT_converter > > > >::reset(CGAL::Lazy > >, CGAL::Sphere_3 >, CGAL::Gmpq, CGAL::Cartesian_converter, CGAL::Simple_cartesian >, CGAL::NT_converter > > >*) in diffgeom.a(Particle.o)
>         boost::thread_specific_ptr > >, CGAL::Sphere_3 >, CGAL::Gmpq, CGAL::Cartesian_converter, CGAL::Simple_cartesian >, CGAL::NT_converter > > > >::~thread_specific_ptr() in diffgeom.a(Particle.o)
>     "_mpfr_clear", referenced from:
>         CGAL::cpp11::result_of > >, CGAL::CartesianKernelFunctors::Compute_squared_radius_3 > > (CGAL::Sphere_3)>::type CGAL::Lazy_construction_nt > >, CGAL::CartesianKernelFunctors::Compute_squared_radius_3 > >::operator() >(CGAL::Sphere_3 const&) const in diffgeom.a(Particle.o)
>         CGAL::Cartesian_converter, CGAL::Simple_cartesian >, CGAL::NT_converter > >::operator()(CGAL::Point_3 > const&) const in diffgeom.a(Particle.o)
>         CGAL::Cartesian_converter, CGAL::Simple_cartesian >, CGAL::NT_converter > >::operator()(CGAL::Sphere_3 > const&) const in diffgeom.a(Particle.o)
>         CGAL::Lazy_rep_1, CGAL::Gmpq, CGAL::CartesianKernelFunctors::Compute_squared_radius_3 > >, CGAL::CartesianKernelFunctors::Compute_squared_radius_3 >, CGAL::To_interval, CGAL::Sphere_3 >::update_exact() const in diffgeom.a(Particle.o)
>         CGAL::cpp11::result_of > >, CGAL::CartesianKernelFunctors::Compute_z_3 > > (CGAL::Point_3)>::type CGAL::Lazy_construction_nt > >, CGAL::CartesianKernelFunctors::Compute_z_3 > >::operator() >(CGAL::Point_3 const&) const in diffgeom.a(Particle.o)
>         CGAL::Lazy_rep_1, CGAL::Gmpq, CGAL::CartesianKernelFunctors::Compute_z_3 > >, CGAL::CartesianKernelFunctors::Compute_z_3 >, CGAL::To_interval, CGAL::Point_3 >::update_exact() const in diffgeom.a(Particle.o)
>         CGAL::cpp11::result_of > >, CGAL::CartesianKernelFunctors::Compute_y_3 > > (CGAL::Point_3)>::type CGAL::Lazy_construction_nt > >, CGAL::CartesianKernelFunctors::Compute_y_3 > >::operator() >(CGAL::Point_3 const&) const in diffgeom.a(Particle.o)
>         ...
>     "_mpfr_get_d", referenced from:
>         CGAL::cpp11::result_of > >, CGAL::CartesianKernelFunctors::Compute_squared_radius_3 > > (CGAL::Sphere_3)>::type CGAL::Lazy_construction_nt > >, CGAL::CartesianKernelFunctors::Compute_squared_radius_3 > >::operator() >(CGAL::Sphere_3 const&) const in diffgeom.a(Particle.o)
>         CGAL::Cartesian_converter, CGAL::Simple_cartesian >, CGAL::NT_converter > >::operator()(CGAL::Point_3 > const&) const in diffgeom.a(Particle.o)
>         CGAL::Cartesian_converter, CGAL::Simple_cartesian >, CGAL::NT_converter > >::operator()(CGAL::Sphere_3 > const&) const in diffgeom.a(Particle.o)
>         CGAL::Lazy_rep_1, CGAL::Gmpq, CGAL::CartesianKernelFunctors::Compute_squared_radius_3 > >, CGAL::CartesianKernelFunctors::Compute_squared_radius_3 >, CGAL::To_interval, CGAL::Sphere_3 >::update_exact() const in diffgeom.a(Particle.o)
>         CGAL::cpp11::result_of > >, CGAL::CartesianKernelFunctors::Compute_z_3 > > (CGAL::Point_3)>::type CGAL::Lazy_construction_nt > >, CGAL::CartesianKernelFunctors::Compute_z_3 > >::operator() >(CGAL::Point_3 const&) const in diffgeom.a(Particle.o)
>         CGAL::Lazy_rep_1, CGAL::Gmpq, CGAL::CartesianKernelFunctors::Compute_z_3 > >, CGAL::CartesianKernelFunctors::Compute_z_3 >, CGAL::To_interval, CGAL::Point_3 >::update_exact() const in diffgeom.a(Particle.o)
>         CGAL::cpp11::result_of > >, CGAL::CartesianKernelFunctors::Compute_y_3 > > (CGAL::Point_3)>::type CGAL::Lazy_construction_nt > >, CGAL::CartesianKernelFunctors::Compute_y_3 > >::operator() >(CGAL::Point_3 const&) const in diffgeom.a(Particle.o)
>         ...
>     "_mpfr_init2", referenced from:
>         CGAL::cpp11::result_of > >, CGAL::CartesianKernelFunctors::Compute_squared_radius_3 > > (CGAL::Sphere_3)>::type CGAL::Lazy_construction_nt > >, CGAL::CartesianKernelFunctors::Compute_squared_radius_3 > >::operator() >(CGAL::Sphere_3 const&) const in diffgeom.a(Particle.o)
>         CGAL::Cartesian_converter, CGAL::Simple_cartesian >, CGAL::NT_converter > >::operator()(CGAL::Point_3 > const&) const in diffgeom.a(Particle.o)
>         CGAL::Cartesian_converter, CGAL::Simple_cartesian >, CGAL::NT_converter > >::operator()(CGAL::Sphere_3 > const&) const in diffgeom.a(Particle.o)
>         CGAL::Lazy_rep_1, CGAL::Gmpq, CGAL::CartesianKernelFunctors::Compute_squared_radius_3 > >, CGAL::CartesianKernelFunctors::Compute_squared_radius_3 >, CGAL::To_interval, CGAL::Sphere_3 >::update_exact() const in diffgeom.a(Particle.o)
>         CGAL::cpp11::result_of > >, CGAL::CartesianKernelFunctors::Compute_z_3 > > (CGAL::Point_3)>::type CGAL::Lazy_construction_nt > >, CGAL::CartesianKernelFunctors::Compute_z_3 > >::operator() >(CGAL::Point_3 const&) const in diffgeom.a(Particle.o)
>         CGAL::Lazy_rep_1, CGAL::Gmpq, CGAL::CartesianKernelFunctors::Compute_z_3 > >, CGAL::CartesianKernelFunctors::Compute_z_3 >, CGAL::To_interval, CGAL::Point_3 >::update_exact() const in diffgeom.a(Particle.o)
>         CGAL::cpp11::result_of > >, CGAL::CartesianKernelFunctors::Compute_y_3 > > (CGAL::Point_3)>::type CGAL::Lazy_construction_nt > >, CGAL::CartesianKernelFunctors::Compute_y_3 > >::operator() >(CGAL::Point_3 const&) const in diffgeom.a(Particle.o)
>         ...
>     "_mpfr_set_q", referenced from:
>         CGAL::cpp11::result_of > >, CGAL::CartesianKernelFunctors::Compute_squared_radius_3 > > (CGAL::Sphere_3)>::type CGAL::Lazy_construction_nt > >, CGAL::CartesianKernelFunctors::Compute_squared_radius_3 > >::operator() >(CGAL::Sphere_3 const&) const in diffgeom.a(Particle.o)
>         CGAL::Cartesian_converter, CGAL::Simple_cartesian >, CGAL::NT_converter > >::operator()(CGAL::Point_3 > const&) const in diffgeom.a(Particle.o)
>         CGAL::Cartesian_converter, CGAL::Simple_cartesian >, CGAL::NT_converter > >::operator()(CGAL::Sphere_3 > const&) const in diffgeom.a(Particle.o)
>         CGAL::Lazy_rep_1, CGAL::Gmpq, CGAL::CartesianKernelFunctors::Compute_squared_radius_3 > >, CGAL::CartesianKernelFunctors::Compute_squared_radius_3 >, CGAL::To_interval, CGAL::Sphere_3 >::update_exact() const in diffgeom.a(Particle.o)
>         CGAL::cpp11::result_of > >, CGAL::CartesianKernelFunctors::Compute_z_3 > > (CGAL::Point_3)>::type CGAL::Lazy_construction_nt > >, CGAL::CartesianKernelFunctors::Compute_z_3 > >::operator() >(CGAL::Point_3 const&) const in diffgeom.a(Particle.o)
>         CGAL::Lazy_rep_1, CGAL::Gmpq, CGAL::CartesianKernelFunctors::Compute_z_3 > >, CGAL::CartesianKernelFunctors::Compute_z_3 >, CGAL::To_interval, CGAL::Point_3 >::update_exact() const in diffgeom.a(Particle.o)
>         CGAL::cpp11::result_of > >, CGAL::CartesianKernelFunctors::Compute_y_3 > > (CGAL::Point_3)>::type CGAL::Lazy_construction_nt > >, CGAL::CartesianKernelFunctors::Compute_y_3 > >::operator() >(CGAL::Point_3 const&) const in diffgeom.a(Particle.o)
>         ...
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>   make: *** [/Users/bullard/ShapeMetrology/Particle/bin/diffgeom] Error 1

Am I missing a CGAL library in the linking command?  Again, I had no trouble when I was using CGAL just to compute a convex hull, but this problem seems to have arisen now that I am trying to include surface meshing.

I will be happy to post relevant parts of the code if that will help, but at this point I don't know which parts would be relevant.

Comment: Missing boost_thread-mt

Comment: If it is possible to use CMake `FindCGAL` will make life much easier for you. It is likely that you are missing other libs also depending on the number types used and what operations you are performing.

Comment: Also missing `-lmpfr` before `-lgmp`.

Comment: Thanks very much!  That helped immensely.  I will look into using CMake from now on, too.